# Merging two Array List in Java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have two Array list say  currentTopicsDetailsList  and  updatedTopicsDetailsList. The Lists are of object Topic(class) i.e.,

```
List<Topic> currentTopicsDetailsList;
List<Topic> updatedTopicsDetailsList;
```

The class Topic has properties

- rank
- socialIndex
- twitterIndex
- newsIndex

I want to update the values in currentTopicsDetailsList with updatedTopicsDetailsList values
e.g. at

- currentTopicsDetailsList[4].rank=158
- currentTopicsDetailsList[4].socialIndex= +245
- currentTopicsDetailsList[4].twitterIndex=-345
- currentTopicsDetailsList[4].newsIndex=+340
- updatedTopicsDetailsLIst[4].rank=null
- updatedTopicsDetailsLIst[4].socialIndex= 300
- updatedTopicsDetailsLIst[4].twitterIndex=-56
- updatedTopicsDetailsLIst[4].newsIndex=+340

I want to overwrite the currentTopicsDetailsList[4] with updatedTopicsDetailsList[4] with a condition that whichever has null should be ignore i.e., rank property should be 158 eventhough its null in updatedTopicsDetailsList[4].rank

Right now am doing it with FOR loop index level comparison for null & empty strings, but is there a alternative and quick way of doing things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put a method in `Topic` class to update

```
public void update(Topic updatedTopic){
   if(updatedTopic.getRank()!=null){
      this.rank = updatedTopic.getRank();
   }
   // similarly u can check others
}
```

and for merging to list you can do like

```
int size = currentTopicsDetailsList.size();
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
  Topic uT = updatedTopicsDetailsLIst.get(i);
  Topic cT = currentTopicsDetailsList.get(i);
  cT.update(uT); 
}
```

Make sure both list contain ordered same `Topic`

Comment: Thanks, but initially i am doing the same.

Comment: Well, since its a urgent fix, i am sticking to the initial one, which is also mentioned by you. So, i am hoping its a genuine way of doing even in production environment scenario.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Set`/`HashSet`. Convert one of list to `Set`. And use `addAll` method.

**Note** Make sure override `equals` and `hashcode` method of `Topic`.

```
List<Topic> currentTopicsDetailsList;
List<Topic> updatedTopicsDetailsList; 
HashSet<Topic> set = new HashSet<Topic>(currentTopicsDetailsList);
set.addAll(updatedTopicsDetailsList);

updatedTopicsDetailsList = new ArrayList<Topic>(set);
```

**Update Comment**

```
 do i have to include all the fields for generating equals() & hascode() ?
```

Sorry, I am not sure, all fields for generating `equals()` & `hascode()` because of it is depend on your requirement.

For example :

`Topic` have a field name with `id`. As two `Topic` instances have same `id`, if we assume these two instance are same, you just need to put `id` into `equals()` & `hascode()`. The rest of fields don't need to put.

Comment: +1 for possibly understanding what the OP was asking for. You should also mention that in addition to equals, hashcode should be overridden too.

Comment: @CycDemo, thanks for the details info,  as per the NOTE-  i need to override equals & hashcode, do i have to include all the fields for  generating equals() & hascode()  ?

Comment: @CycDemo i am not sure how this answer will solve problem, usually `set.addAll(anotherset)` will invoke `equals` method and add missing object. if duplicates found will simply reject.

Comment: @Stivel, I told that, it is depend on requirement. Normally, we put all of fields.

Comment: @CycDemo his requirement is merging two `Topic` objects based on some comparison not merging to Topic Lists.

Comment: actually, when i tried  the Hashset and addAll() method, the objects within the List are not updating, rathing more objects are added i.e., if the initial list has 10 Topic objects and if i modify values of 3 objects, then the update list has 13 objects instead of 10.

Comment: @SangramAnand Taht would be the case if the objects being added are not equal to any of those already contained in the set, or if you break the contract for hashcode and equals. (Read on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link, will look into it and update the status shortly.